# How to reset an scene in Cocos2d?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

How can I reset an scene (restart the countdown and set the score to 0) the second time I start it? The second time I load the scene both initWithParameters and onStart are not called.

Cocos2D Game:

```
  -(id) initWithParameters:(NSArray *) parameters
{
    NSLog(@"init TheButton with parameters");

    // Apple recommend assigning self with supers return value
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return(nil);

   gameParameters = parameters;

    // Enable touch handling on scene node
    [self setIsTouchEnabled:YES];

    // Create a colored background (Dark Grey)
    //CCNodeColor *background = [CCNodeColor nodeWithColor:[CCColor colorWithRed:0.6f green:0.6f blue:0.6f alpha:1.0f]];
    //[self addChild:background];

    CCMenuItem *starMenuItem = [CCMenuItemImage
                                itemFromNormalImage:@"ButtonStar.png" selectedImage:@"ButtonStarSel.png"
                                target:self selector:@selector(increasePoints:)];
    CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    starMenuItem.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5f,0.5f);
    starMenuItem.position = ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2);
    CCMenu *starMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:starMenuItem, nil];
    starMenu.position = CGPointZero;
    [self addChild:starMenu];

    timeLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0.00" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:18.0f];
    //timeLabel.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
    timeLabel.position = ccp(30,size.height-10);
    // Add the time label
    [self addChild:timeLabel];
    NSLog(@"time: %@", [gameParameters objectAtIndex:0]);

    clicksLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0" fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:18.0f];
    //clicksLabel.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
    clicksLabel.position = ccp(size.width - 20,size.height-10);
    // Add the time label
    [self addChild:clicksLabel];

    [self startGame];

    return self;
}


-(void) startGame
{
    clicks = 0;
    myTime = [[gameParameters objectAtIndex:0] intValue];

    [self schedule:@selector(update:)];

}
```

The scene (a cocos2d game) is integrated in a storyboard project. When it finishes (the countdown arrives to 0) it loads a new viewcontroller. From this viewcontroller I would like to load the game again when when the user press the "Play Again" Button.  What happens is the scene is loading (I implemented it with an unwind segue) but both the countdown and the score are not reseted, how can I do this?

[image]

EDIT:
I finally get to reload and reset the scene from the CocosViewController but when I call performSegueWithIdentifier when the game finishes it does not load the viewcontroller. Method viewdidload is called but it does not show anything.

Cocos2dGame:

```
-(void) onExit
{
[super onExit];

//Send parameters
self.gameTracking = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"THE",@"QUICK", @"BROWN", @"FOX",@"FOO", nil];
NSDictionary * userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",clicks], @"score", self.gameTracking, @"gameTracking", nil];

//Send a notification to the CocosViewController when the game is finished to load the new view controller
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"GameEndedNotification" object:self userInfo:userInfo];

NSLog(@"game exit");

//[[CCDirector sharedDirector] end];
```

}

Cocos2DViewController

```
 //Receive notification when the game finished
-(void)receiveNotificationFromGame:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"GameEndedNotification"])
    {
        NSLog (@"Successfully received the test notification! %@", [self class]);
        NSLog(@"score: %d", [notification.userInfo[@"score"] intValue]);

    //get variables
    try.score = [notification.userInfo[@"score"] intValue];
    NSLog(@"score: %d", try.score);

    try.gameTracking = notification.userInfo[@"gameTracking"];

    //show the next view
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sg_showScore" sender:self];
}
```

}

Comment: In general the easiest way is to use the `CCDirector` to load you scene again.

Comment: @Ben-G I finally get to load it by replacethescene but now when I performaseguewithidentifier it does not load the new view (althought the viewdidload method of the new view is called). How can I solve this?